# Matching higher-kinded types in SYB

Tags: haskell, generic-programming, scrap-your-boilerplate, rank-n-types

In general, I'm wondering if there's a way to write a generic fold that generalizes a function that applies a `forall` type like:

```
f :: forall a. Data (D a) => D a -> b
```

given some datatype `D` for which `instance Data (D a)` (possibly with constraints on `a`). To be concrete, consider something even as simple as `` False `mkQ` isJust ``, or generally, a query on the constructor of a higher-kinded datatype. Similarly, consider a transformation `mkT (const Nothing)` that only affects one particular higher-kinded type.

Without explicit type signatures, they fail with `No instance for Typeable a0`, which is probably the monomorphism restriction at work. Fair enough. However, if we add explicit type signatures:

```
t :: GenericT
t = mkT (const Nothing :: forall a. Data a => Maybe a -> Maybe a)
q :: GenericQ Bool
q = False `mkQ` (isJust :: forall a. Data a => Maybe a -> Bool)
```

instead we are told that the `forall` type of the outer signatures are ambiguous:

```
Could not deduce (Typeable a0)
   arising from a use of ‘mkT’
from the context: Data a
   bound by the type signature for:
              t :: GenericT
The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
```

I can't wrap my head around this. If I'm really understanding correctly that `a0` is the variable in `t :: forall a0. Data a0 => a0 -> a0`, how is it any more ambiguous than in say `mkT not`? If anything, I would've expected `mkT` to complain because it is the one that interacts with `isJust`. Additionally, these functions are more polymorphic than the branching on concrete types.

I'm curious to know if this is a limitation of proving the inner constraint `isJust :: Data a => ...` — my understanding is that any type of instance `Data` inhabited with `Maybe a` must also have `Data a` to be valid by the instance constraint `instance Data a => Data (Maybe a)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

tldr: You need to create a different function.

`mkT` has the following signature:

```
mkT :: (Typeable a, Typeable b) => (a -> a) -> (b -> b)
```

And you want to apply it to a polymorphic function of type `(forall x. Maybe x -> Maybe x)`. It is not possible: there is no way to instantiate `a` in `(a -> a)` to obtain `(forall x. Maybe x -> Maybe x)`.

It's not just a limitation of the type system, the implementation of `mkT` wouldn't support such an instantiation either.

`mkT` simply compares concrete types `a` and `b` for equality at run time. But what you want is to be able to test whether `b` is equal to `Maybe x` for some `x`. The logic this requires is fundamentally more involved. **But it is certainly still possible.**

Below, `mkT1` first matches the type `b` against the `App` pattern to know whether `b` is some type application `g y`, and then tests equality of `g` and `f`:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, RankNTypes, TypeApplications, GADTs #-}

import Type.Reflection

-- N.B.: You can add constraints on (f x), but you must do the same for b.
mkT1 :: forall f b. (Typeable f, Typeable b) => (forall x. f x -> f x) -> (b -> b)
mkT1 h =
  case typeRep @b of
    App g y ->
      case eqTypeRep g (typeRep @f) of
        Just HRefl -> h
        _ -> id
    _ -> id
```

---

Compilable example with `mkQ1` as well:

```hs
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables, RankNTypes, TypeApplications, GADTs #-}

import Type.Reflection

mkT1 :: forall f b. (Typeable f, Typeable b) => (forall x. f x -> f x) -> (b -> b)
mkT1 h =
  case typeRep @b of
    App g y ->
      case eqTypeRep g (typeRep @f) of
        Just HRefl -> h
        _ -> id
    _ -> id

mkQ1 :: forall f b q. (Typeable f, Typeable b) => (forall x. f x -> q) -> (b -> q) -> (b -> q)
mkQ1 h =
  case typeRep @b of
    App g y ->
      case eqTypeRep g (typeRep @f) of
        Just HRefl -> const h
        _ -> id
    _ -> id

f :: Maybe x -> String
f _ = "matches"

main :: IO ()
main = do
  print (mkQ1 f (\_ -> "doesn't match") (Just 3 :: Maybe Int))  -- matches
  print (mkQ1 f (\_ -> "doesn't match") (3 :: Int))             -- doesn't match
```